# Error in the constainstable arguments

Tags: sql-server

I need help in my query. I have a search system and it works perfectly when only a word is submitted ihe the search All works good.

But if two or more terms are submitted, the results aren't good. In this case, My system don't return any result for me, when two or more terms are submitted in the search.

I think that the problem is in my query. Is there any problem with this query?

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    p.id, p.title, p.description, date_pusblish AS datep, p.typep, p.idvisible ,(100 * coalesce(sr1.RANK, 0) + 10 * coalesce(sr2.RANK, 0) + 1 * coalesce(sr3.RANK, 0)) AS rank 
FROM 
    publish_posts pp, posts p 
LEFT JOIN 
    containstable(posts,(title),'"creating" AND "a" AND "virtual" AND "store" AND "with" AND "php"') AS sr1
    ON p.id = sr1.[KEY] 
LEFT JOIN
    containstable(posts,(description),'"creating" AND "a" AND "virtual" AND "store" AND "with" AND "php"') AS sr2
    ON p.id = sr2.[KEY] 
LEFT JOIN
    containstable(posts,(conteudo),'"creating" AND "a" AND "virtual" AND "store" AND "with" AND "php"') AS sr3
   ON p.id = sr3.[KEY] 
WHERE 
    p.languagesys <> 3
     AND p.id = pp.id
     AND (p.visible IS NULL OR p.visible >= 0)
     AND (p.published IS NULL OR p.published >= 0)
     AND p.typep <> 2
     AND (p.id = sr1.[KEY] OR p.id = sr2.[KEY] OR p.id = sr3.[KEY])
     AND (100 * coalesce(sr1.RANK, 0) + 10 * coalesce(sr2.RANK, 0) + 1 * coalesce(sr3.RANK, 0)) > 100
 ORDER BY 
    date_pusblish DESC, p.id DESC
```

Comment: Are you certain that any records actually match all these search terms?  Also, you are mixing old style joins (`publish_posts` and `posts`) with new style joins.

Comment: Can you show your data in these fields? Also, in the examples I don't see any double quotes around the words. Try removing them. Also, replace `AND` with `OR` to see if you get results.

Comment: Have you tried running just the ContainsTable statements (select * from containstable...)? That will help you determine if the problem is the containsTable or if the problem is something else.

Comment: Hello Tim, yes. The results returns to me with one term. With two or more not.

Comment: Hi WEI_DBA I  did what you suggested. I changed "AND" for "OR". And returned results for me. But not the most relevant

Comment: Jeff, I'll try this now